# Can't find variable : Dimensions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've been getting this error in the project since I pulled expo to version 44.

The error image is attached.
[image: failimage]

What I tried could not solve the problem?

Comment: ReactNative/Expo errors stack error cause snippets are most time misleading. Make use that your code does not use Dimensions API - actual device width and height without importing it.

Comment: Thats be possible. I will search that you said and I will inform with comment to you

Comment: We can have 1:1 meeting in case you need personal assistance at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com

Comment: Ohoo. Thanks for that. I will send pm on there

Comment: @BYIRINGIRO: there is no explicit prohibition on moving assistance to a private forum. However I wonder if offering commercial support services it is not quite within the spirit of the Stack Overflow community. I wonder if you would be better making this clear in your profile, explain how you offer your services, and then ask people to visit your profile. That way people can make an informed decision as to whether it is worth contacting you.

Comment: I offer 1:1 assistance mainly for free. When developers need extra assistance or write a custom solution, they can pay for services. Anyway, Thanks for the suggestion and I will update profile to remove confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactNative/Expo errors stack error cause snippets are most time misleading. Make use that your code does not use Dimensions API - actual device width and height without importing it. via @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

Check you have dimensions or not. Also check where the component dimension is coming from.

Comment: Hi I checked and I writed comments now